# Prophet - saturation forecast minimum goes below 0

Tags: python, pandas, prediction, forecast, facebook-prophet

I'm doing a prophet prediction for a dataframe with call count and I tried to do a logistic growth model for it.
Dataframe has ds column; 30min datetime bins and y column; call count for each bin

Here's the prediction code

```
dataframe['cap']=10000
dataframe['floor']=0

m = Prophet(growth='logistic')
m.fit(dataframe)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods=periods, freq='H')
    
future['cap']=10000
future['floor']=0
        
forecast = m.predict(future)
fig1 = m.plot(forecast, xlabel='Date-time DD-MM-YY:HH-MM-SS', ylabel='Call Count')
plt.title('Forecast Prediction')
plt.show()
```

and graph

[image]

Even after that the detected pattern graph and forecast both goes below zero.
Why is this happening and What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, a common technique to handle negative values in prediction models is the logarithmic trasformation.

To transform your target variable , you can use `Y=log(x + c)` where `c` is the constant.

People usually choose something like `Y=log(x+1)` or any other "very small" positive number.

After this transformation, it's impossible to get negative values from forecasting.

To come back to original scale just use the inverse function of `y=log(x+1)` , that is `y = exp(x)-1`